# Do I need to wrap all my <input> elements in <form> elements?

Tags: html, forms

I am using JavaScript to extract values from some `<input>` elements in my page.

Do I need to wrap all my `<input>` elements in `<form>` elements?

What will happen if I do not?

Does it give access to some better features?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No you don't.

The form is used to send data to the server, like some kind of search mask to query a database.

You can put all your input tags in one form tag.

There are some advantages using a form:

1. Some browsers save the data and you don't have to reenter it
2. You can easily send it by pushing enter, not just by clicking on a button

Rule of thumb: If you have some input elements that logically belong together, then put them in a form. To process the data you can either use javascript (onsubmit) or you can send it directly to the server.

Comment: So, is that like a way to send data to the server without using JavaScript?  Is that kind of why the form elements are there?

Comment: @timbram: Yes, sending a form using a submit button is the usual way of sending form data to the server, and doesn't require any JavaScript.

Comment: How the forms are typically used changed over time. You could use no form and then send the data on a button click event or you can use a form and specify an action and a submit button, then the data is sent by pushing on the button or enter in an input, unless you intervene and return false onsubmit

Comment: @timbram added a rule of thumb, maybe that helps you